# Why no PHB tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Why is there no PHB tag?  Is it copyrighted?

I'm working on a question where this would be an (arguably) appropriate tag, but I see that it doesn't exist.

Comment: And precisely what does PHB stand for in this case?

Comment: It isn't Friday yet.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss

Comment: which site are you asking about?  Meta?  SO?  SF?  SU?  i can see potential usefulness on SF, somewhat less so on SO, none whatsoever on SU, and only as a humorous tag on Meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag does not exist because it is off-topic by definition.  The trilogy sites are for specific technical questions, not career advice, which is what a "PHB" tag would pertain to.

If this is indeed what your question is about, please consider not posting it.

Comment: I understand that these questions tend to be subjective and hence better avoided.  But sometimes a PHB may impact your ability to perform your technical function.  If the impact can be mitigated by a sufficiently narrow technical argument then might the question be asked?

Comment: What you have for breakfast can impact your ability to concentrate and work. But it's still not a programming question. @unc

Comment: It might be peripherally on topic in some cases, in which technical issues get mixed with project management.  (It isn't career advice; I don't think anybody here would advise a career path to PHB.)  However, as we're seeing it isn't universal, and that's another big problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

If it IS appropriate and it ain't there, create it already :)

But pardon my ignorance, what is PHB? Brother of PHP?

Comment: Pointy haired boss, maybe... http://dilbert.com/

Answer (score 1):

Would it be wise to actually use a PHB tag if it did exist?

The kind of bosses that people typically refer to as PHBs are also typically the sort of people who keep an eye on their employee's internet usage.

Do you really want your boss finding out that you're insulting him on the internet? Good career move, that.